# Why isn't random.sample(items, 1) == to any item in the list?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python, and I'm stuck in this sample code I've made.

```
from random import *

items = ["high", "low"]
quantity = sample(items, 1)  # Pick 1 random items from the list


def start():
    if  quantity == "high":
        print ("Quantity is high")
    else:
        print ("Quantity is low")


start()
```

I always get "Quantity is low", but if I use "if high in quantity", like this:

```
def start():
    if  "high" in quantity:
        print ("Quantity is high")
    else:
        print ("Quantity is low")
```

Then is right. I don't know why == is not working. Thanks!

Comment: `random.sample(items, 1)` doesn't return something like `"high"` -- instead, it returns something like `["high"]`.

Comment: `sample` returns a *list* which will never equal a string... You probably want `random.choice`

Comment: BTW, you could probably have found this yourself if you'd tried printing `repr(quantity)`.

Comment: yes, print debugging is always a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) returns a `list`.

If you want a single entry returned, look into [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) instead. Then `==` will work as you expect.